# How to make icon square?

Tags: firefox-addon, png

I am  uploading simple extension on mozila & it's showing  **Error: Icon at "logo.png" must be square.**  What is error mean and How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if your icons are `svg`s or if the icon's `width` & `hight` don't have the same size.
Like the message says, it should be squares.